# How do you interpret this assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

Extracted from nginx:

```
static ngx_inline ngx_atomic_uint_t
ngx_atomic_cmp_set(ngx_atomic_t *lock, ngx_atomic_uint_t old,
ngx_atomic_uint_t set)
{
    u_char res;
    __asm__ volatile (
    NGX_SMP_LOCK
    " cmpxchgl %3, %1; "
    " sete %0; "
    : "=a" (res) : "m" (*lock), "a" (old), "r" (set) : "cc", "memory");
    return res;
}
```

I don't understand the syntax the assembly instruction are combined(it's using a different syntax than `printf` uses),what is it doing at all?

Comment: http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given [this](http://lxr.evanmiller.org/http/source/os/unix/ngx_gcc_atomic_x86.h#L8) and ignoring operations atomicity, function is equivalent to:

```
 static ngx_inline ngx_atomic_uint_t
 ngx_atomic_cmp_set(ngx_atomic_t *lock, ngx_atomic_uint_t old,
 ngx_atomic_uint_t set)
 {
     u_char res;
     if (*lock == old){
         *lock = set;
         res = 1;
     } else{
         res = *lock
     }
     return res;
  }
```